# How to export SAS Dataset which is more than 350mb to excel sheet

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a unique dataset and I need to export to excel. It contains 10 million rows with 300 columns.

I have tried to proc export

```
proc export data = Work.a outfile= "Q:\Work.a.xlsx"
dbms=xlsx replace ;
run;
```

Keep on getting error message of  Too many numbers of records to be exported

Can you please help me or tell me how to fix it

Comment: What's the limit on an Excel file, how many records can it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Excel limitation, not a SAS limitation. Excel files are limited to approximately 1 million records and 16k columns. You could try and reshape your data, but really, working with an Excel file with that many records would be painful.

See Microsoft notes on limits here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 0):

Try summarising your data over all variables of interest before exporting to excel. The summary will be much easier to work with than the full dataset if your goal is just produce some high-level charts or something like that.

Alternatively, export as CSV, and then you have the option of defining the csv as a data source that you can feed in to a pivot table, even if it exceeds the usual excel row limit. This will still be really slow to work with, though - it doesn't get around the fundamental issue that excel struggles to cope with datasets beyond a certain size.